# I am pushing a block by my hands with a force $F$ since block is in contact with my hand so my hand will apply normal force on the block $N_1$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

[image]

N1 here is the normal force my handexert on the block due to contact between block and my hand.

F is the external force which i apply
N is the normal force with surface applies on the block.

So my question is the fbd right or wrong and why?

Comment: Why do you have two forces acting towards the right ($F_{ext}$ and $N_{1}$) where the only force you are applying to the block is $F_{ext}$ ?

Comment: Since my hands are in contact with the block surface so there will be normal force acting on my hand and the block which is N1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $F_{ext}$ is the normal force. Both are same , when your hand is in contact with the block's surface , The normal interaction is the external force , because the particles in the block do repel your hand and the same repulsion is felt in the block which creates the external force you mentioned !

So there is really only one force acting on the block

Comment: you can ask yourself , If there is  a normal force on the block , then how did your external force create  ? What type of force it is to better understand that they are the same force

Comment: What if I apply external force  to an  angle then also we can say that ext force is the normal force

Comment: yes ! the horizontal component is the force for moving towards the right , the angle doesn't matter for the nature of force the interactions between the particles such that they have a repulsion force is what the normal force is and here it is the external force

Comment: Thank you very much